# While Loop wait Interrupt Handler

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program to program a microcontroller. In practice, when an interrupt handler occurs I go to execute the following code:

```
uint8_t call_irq_handler = 0; // variable that is modified by the irq handler
uint8_t call_irq_handler_previous = 0;

static __attribute__((interrupt)) void __irq_handler()
{
    call_irq_handler_previous = call_irq_handler;
    call_irq_handler = call_irq_handler + 1;
}
```

In main, instead, to wait for the interrupt handler to be executed, I put the following while loop:

```
while (call_irq_handler == call_irq_handler_previous)
{
    count_cmd_write++;
#if DEBUG
    printf("...i didn't get interrupt handler for cmd_write...\n");
#else
    continue;
#endif
}
```

If I set DEBUG 1, I have no problem, the code is executed and after a while I exit the while loop. However, if DEBUG 0 then I remain in the while, and therefore the interrupt handler is not taken.
Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Is `call_irq_handler_previous` volatile?

Comment: No, it is not volatile.

Comment: Duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409545/using-volatile-in-embedded-c-development/409570#409570

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by going to insert volatile

```
 volatile uint8_t call_irq_handler = 0; // variable that is modified by the irq handler
        volatile uint8_t call_irq_handler_previous = 0;
```